# How to get a Shiny's updateSelectionInput to update with a list of values

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, shiny, reactive

I'm trying to populate a list based on a user's previous selection. For example, if the user selects "B1_B2" from my second dropdown list, the third dropdown should show sublist_12.  The only problem is that my code only updates the dropdown box with the first item in sublist_12.  How do I get it to populate the dropdown with the full set of elements?  (Also, I'm totally open to more elegant ways of doing this.  Feel free to tell me if this is horribly inefficient).  Thanks!

```
library(shiny)

list_A <- c("A1","A2","A3")
list_B <- c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B1_B2")
sublist_1 <- c("X","Y")
sublist_2 <- c("Z")
sublist_12 <- c("foo", "boo", "zoo")

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Select Category"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        selectInput(inputId = "listA_options", label = "Select Cateroy", 
choices = c(list_A, list_B)),
        selectInput(inputId = "listB_options", label = "Select subcat1", 
choices = list_B),
        selectInput(inputId = "sublist_options", label = "Select subcat2", 
choices = NULL))),
mainPanel(  )))

server <- function(input, output, session) 
{
  #Update the Selection options
  choices_interventions <- reactive({
    choices_interventions <- ifelse(input$listB_options == "B1", sublist_1, 
                                    ifelse(input$listB_options == "B2", sublist_1,
                                           ifelse(input$listB_options == "B3", sublist_2,
                                                  ifelse(input$listB_options == "B1_B2", sublist_12))))})
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = "sublist_options", choices = choices_interventions())
  })
 }

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to be careful when we use `ifelse()` its a vectorized form of ifelse not just a more convenient way of writing `if(condition) ... else ...`.

For future knowledge, in `ifelse(condition,true,false)` `true` and `false` are both evaluated. The vectors are then subset using the condition.

Example: `ifelse(c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE),c(1,2,3,4,5),c(6,7,8,9,10)) = [1,2,8,9,5]`

Anyway, the reason it was showing only the first element is because your conditional statement `input$listB_options == "B1"` is one dimensional. You're better off using the regular `if() else` or even better a switch statement.

```
library(shiny)

list_A <- c("A1","A2","A3")
list_B <- c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B1_B2")
sublist_1 <- c("X","Y")
sublist_2 <- c("Z")
sublist_12 <- c("foo", "boo", "zoo")

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Select Category"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        selectInput(inputId = "listA_options", label = "Select Cateroy", 
                    choices = c(list_A, list_B)),
        selectInput(inputId = "listB_options", label = "Select subcat1", 
                    choices = list_B),
        selectInput(inputId = "sublist_options", label = "Select subcat2", 
                    choices = NULL))),
    mainPanel(  )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #Update the Selection options
  choices_interventions <- reactive({

  switch(input$listB_options,
         "B1" = sublist_1,
         "B2" = sublist_1,
         "B3" = sublist_2,
         "B1_B2" = sublist_12)
  })



  observe({
    req(choices_interventions())
    updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = "sublist_options", choices = choices_interventions())
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That makes so much sense! Thank you so much.  I just implemented it on my script and it's perfect.  Much appreciated, Sada93!